# Ember route getting empty model after successful promise

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've built a `RESTAdapter` to work with `couchdb`, and am testing it to make sure it works, and so far things seem fine, but my test route seems to be having other problems.

Sorry this is so long, I probably ought to set up a fiddle for it... I've just never done that before, but will look into it right now....

I've built the following (relevant) things:

```
App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
    rev: DS.attr(),
    price: DS.attr()
});

App.Things<Index>Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.get('store').findAll('thing');
    }
});
```

(I've tried `ThingsRoute` with and without the `Index` without any change)

In `App.Router.map`:

```
this.resource('things', function() {
    this.route('thing', { path: ':thing_id'})
});
```

In `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend`:

```
buildURL: function(type, id) {
    id = id || '_all_docs?include_docs=true';
    return this._super(type, id);
}
```

In `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend`:

```
extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    root = type.typeKey;
    root = Ember.String.pluralize(root);
    newJSON = {};

    newJSON[root] = payload.rows.map(function(row) {
        return row.doc;
    });
    payload = newJSON;

    console.log(payload);
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
},

normalize: function(type, hash, property) {
    var json = { id: hash._id, rev: hash._rev};
    delete hash._id;
    delete hash._rev;

    for (var prop in hash) {
        json[prop] = hash[prop]; 
    }

    console.log(json);
    return this._super(type, json, property);
}
```

And this template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things/index">
    {{#each thing in things}}
        {{thing.rev}}
        {{thing.price}}
    {{else}}
        Empty.
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

The `console.log`s in `extractArray` and `normalize` both show the following perfectly formatted and correct json:

```
Object {things: Array[3]}
Object {id: "8117701d38cf9a1112ce8ed38000064d", rev: "1-14918623fedb103cf035ff2489e0a6a1", price: 1}
Object {id: "8117701d38cf9a1112ce8ed3800006e5", rev: "1-09b1e6aa1fb391e11c90bca86daccb7a", price: 5}
Object {id: "8117701d38cf9a1112ce8ed38000144e", rev: "1-2a682bf7ce58829ad2054bb8f5fbe869", price: 4}
```

but when the template is rendered it simply shows `Empty`, and when I replace the `model` hook in the `ThingsRoute` to this:

```
return {things: [{id: 1, rev: 234, price: 4}, {id: 2, rev: 235, price: 3}]};
```

it works exactly as expected. AND when I define `afterModel`:

```
afterModel: function(things, transition) {
    console.log(things);
    console.log(transition);
}
```

It logs this:

```
Class {type: function, store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: false, toString: function…}
Transition {router: Router, promise: Promise, data: Object, resolvedModels: Object, providedModels: Object…}
```

that `Class` object has this:

```
content: Array[3]
  0: Class
  1: Class
  2: Class
```

and each of THOSE `Class`es has an `id` field corresponding to my objects.

What's happening? Why isn't my route getting that model even after the Adapter seems to do it's job perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is because the `things` variable in your template, doesn't exist, try to update to `model`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things/index">
    {{#each thing in model}}
        {{thing.rev}}
        {{thing.price}}
    {{else}}
        Empty.
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Or if you want that variable you can create a alias in your controller:

```
App.ThingsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    things: Ember.computed.alias('model')
});
```

Comment: Good catch, additionaly you could use {{#each thing}}, {{#each thing in controller}},

Comment: Bingo, both worked, and I'm going with the change to `model` since it doesn't require any extra `js` Can you explain why the `things` array isn't passed by name? And also why simply `{{#each thing}}` didn't work? I am missing something here.

Comment: And @Daniel `{{#each thing}}` didn't work but `{{#each thing in controller}}` did.

Comment: the things property is only used for parsing out the things objects for ember data.  Once you return it from the hook it's property name is model/content in the controller.  The controller will proxy get/set requests to sent to it down to the model.

Comment: And yeah, that first one was totally incorrect, I meant it like so {{#each}} inside of here the context will be thing, so you could do {{rev}}{{price}}{{this}} etc {{/each}}, Personally I prefer {{#each item in controller}}

Answer (score 0):

You should be using find instead of findAll

Comment: Do you have associated Controllers?

Comment: I didn't think that would be necessary, since there's no control logic and `Ember` hooks all of that up implicitly by naming. Is there a reason why that could make a difference?

Comment: It isn't necessary, I was just checking if you had any controllers that could be breaking it.

Comment: BTW, for future reference use emberjs.jsbin.com for setting up your project for reference (it at least as some of the framework setup for you).

Comment: Marcio probably has your answer.